# How to fix "[WinError 2] System cannot find the file specified" in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sublimetext3

I'm trying to sync my AWS S3 bucket with my local files using Sublime Text 3.

I have installed AWS CLI and configured with my S3 access keys.

To perform my desired oepration, I have created a file named s3sync.sublime-build which contains the following code:

```
{
"cmd":["aws","s3","sync","C:\\Users\\john\\OneDrive\\Documents\\folder\\sub 1\\sub 2","s3://s3url.com"]
}
```

I then created a file called `test.txt` in my "sub 2" folder to test the sync/build system.

When I press "ctrl + B" I receive the following error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['aws', 's3', 'sync','C:\\Users\\john\\OneDrive\\Documents\\folder\\sub 1\\sub 2', 's3://s3url.com']]
[dir: C:\Users\john\OneDrive\Documents\folder\sub 1\sub 2]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps]
[Finished]
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The list of directories displayed after `[path:` in the error output are the places that Windows is looking for a program named `aws`; if it's not installed in any of those places, then `The system cannot find the file specified`. In that case, you need to add the location where `aws` is located to the `PATH` environment variable in Windows and restart Sublime.

Comment: Thanks. I have confirmed that `aws` is installed in C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\.  This location is already added as a `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: If you open a command prompt and try to run the command manually, does it work?

Comment: Forgive me I'm very new to this. I actually am not sure how I would run the command manually in the command prompt. I.e. What would I enter after `C:\Users\john>` ?

Comment: The same thing that is in the `cmd` in your build (there is no magic, Sublime is just telling windows to run that program with that arguments). So you would enter `aws s3 sync "C:\\Users\\john\\OneDrive\\Documents\\folder\\sub 1\\sub 2" s3://s3url.com`. If that doesn't work, then it won't work in Sublime either.

Comment: It worked when I ran it manually in the command prompt. I would still like to use build within Sublime to upload files, curious if this information helps to narrow the issue or if there is anything else I should try? Really appreciate the help so far.

Comment: You might have some luck adding `"shell": true` to your `sublime-build` file (make sure that there's a comma between that line and the `cmd` line or the file won't be valid JSON). Failing that, swapping to `shell_cmd` from `cmd` might help, but I'd try the shell thing first.

Comment: Adding `"shell": true` worked, thanks so much!